# How do you display attributes for different products?

Tags: magento-1.9, attributes, product-attribute, onepage-checkout, phtml

i want to **add a attribute** to products **in the cart** of my magento-shop.
The problem is **not all of the products have the attribute color.** If a product has no attribute "color" **the value of the previous product will be displayed** - so f.e. the first product is white, the second has no color. Now there will be displayed PRODUCT 1 Color: white and PRODUCT 2 Color: white (actually this isn't right, **it has no color at all**).

Help would be appreciated!

The code i use in default.phtml:

```
<?php $_item = $this->getItem() ?>
<?php $_product= Mage::getSingleton('catalog/product')->load($_item->getProductId()) ?>
<?php echo 'Color: '.$_product->getResource()->getAttribute('color')->getFrontend()->getValue($_product).'<br>'; ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `model` instead `singleton` or add one check as attribute exist in the product or not. Below both codes should work.

Try code 1:

```
<?php $_item = $this->getItem() ?>
<?php $_product= Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load($_item->getProductId()) ?>
<?php echo 'Color: '.$_product->getResource()->getAttribute('color')->getFrontend()->getValue($_product).'<br>'; ?>
```

Try code 2 (Recommended):

```
<?php $_item = $this->getItem() ?>
<?php $_product= Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load($_item->getProductId()) ?>

<?php $eavConfig = Mage::getModel('eav/config');
$attributes = $eavConfig->getEntityAttributeCodes(
Mage_Catalog_Model_Product::ENTITY,$_product);
if (in_array('color',$attributes)) {?>

<?php echo 'Color: '.$_product->getResource()->getAttribute('color')->getFrontend()->getValue($_product).'<br>'; ?>

<?php } ?>
```